How to highlight multiple words at a single time in pdf file using pdf.js
I am trying to highlight words in the pdf file using pdf.js library. What i want is to highlight words which are not in a sequence format. like a sentence in the pdf file is "text of the printing, typesetting industry". I want to highlight printing and industry in this line.

I have tried to pass data in the array but nothing work.

http://terfa.com/reglement/39/206/39206_rapport_20140623.pdf#search=HighlightWords
Highlight Words is the array of Words need to be highlighted in the pdf file.

I have also tried to pass data in the list and use each loop to highlight word but it highlight the last word of the list.

$.each(HighlightWords,function(val,data){ http://terfa.com/reglement/39/206/39206_rapport_20140623.pdf#search=data });

PDF.js can use a "quoted spaced" case insensitive array of letters in groups.
Note the first letter group found is highlighted in pale green but all duplicates and other groups are in pink (pale red).
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html#page=4&search=%22An%20or%20de%20red%20spaced%20letters%20array%22

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html#page=4&search=%22An%20or%20de%20red%20spaced%20letters%20array%22

Note that Adobe defined the method and behaves differently, so it goes to page 4 then jumps back to the first page matching word in the list. (Here the second word from "an abstract" but all others are listed on the left)

Note also that Adobe Acrobat plug-in only accepts whole words not an in title Languages
From Page 994 of the ISO standard [emphasis mine]

search - wordList - Open the document and search for one or more words,   selecting the first matching word in the document. The wordList argument defines the search words and shall be a string enclosed within quotation marks comprised of individual words separated by space characters.

Chromium's PDFium have never natively supported search to date. So even MS Edge with either Acrobat DC or "Powered by Acrobat" plugins also dont do search ! (Internet Explorer did)
